# Webpack production version of website points to the wrong directories

Tags: javascript, json, webpack, directory

I have two npm commands `"build": "webpack --mode production"` and `"start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"`. When I run the `start` command the web application runs as intended with all the CSS and javascript being transpiled correctly.
However when I run `build` the fils are generated as intended and when the main HTML file is opened the href and src do not point to the correct directories.

I looked at my webpack.config.js and it appears to be working as intended which leads me to a bit of head-scratching. Changing the HTML template causes the development version to break and have the production version work as intended. The intention is for both development and production version to work as intended.

For reference here is my directory structure:

```
root
  |-.vscode
  |-dist
  |  |-css
  |  |-img
  |  |-js
  |    |- output location for bundle.js index.html main.css
  |-node.modules
  |-src
     |-css
     |  |-scss
     |-js
     |  |-JSON
     |  |-models
     |  |-view
     |  |-app.js
     |-index.html
     |-.babelrc
     |-package-lock.json
     |-package.json
     |-webpack.config.js
```

Webpack config file

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const babelLoader = require("babel-loader");

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        "babel-polyfill","./src/js/app.js"
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/js"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./dist"
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename:"index.html",
            template:"./src/index.html"
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                },
                {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true,
                        modules: true,
                        localIdentName: "[local]"
                    }
                },
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            }

        ]
    }
}
```

and package.json

```
{
  "name": "tempName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
  },
  "author": "Fake Name",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.7.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "sortablejs": "^1.10.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "pokedex-promise-v2": "^3.2.0"
  }
}
```

How do I specify the href(s) and src(s) in the HTML document to link to the CSS and javascript since they are added during the build script and are not in the HTML template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these things:
1) instead of setting contentBase to dev-server try to set `'publicPath: '/'`
2) set `'output.publicPath'` to `'/'` also
3) if previous doesn't work, `HtmlWepbpackPlugin` has `base` option to add prefix for loaded scripts. but i strongly recommend to handle it with public path.

PS: fix your prod build, and only when fix webpack-dev-server. it will be easier

Comment: It got the job done but I think I'm still misunderstanding how WebPack packages my website data. I have images that display in the dev but can be found in the production. `../img/item/002.png`. The browser seems to still think that I want to pull images from the root of the drive and not the relative directory.